# Visualize polygon as point OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 5 for visualizing some polygons I get from a GeoJSON file.
I would like to style them with markers at the center of each, but no idea how to start. Styling them as polygons is ok. 
Now I would like to iterate through all the features, and get their center, so that would be a layer to style.

Comment: It's easy using a geometry function in the style to display the interior points https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-label-decluttering-wh55q

Comment: Thank you, it completely worked. never thought it would be that easy